# Why is Anaconda Prompt showing to directories?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I open Anaconda Prompt and this is what I see
Why is it giving 2 directories? the only way to fix this temporarily is typing cd Anaconda2, but it should say (C:\Users\Darkkewi\Anaconda2 without the second portion C:.... Image below shows I what I am speaking of

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz9Bv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just does. I opened mine to double check and this is what I got.

[image]

Comment: wow thank you for the feed back this was literally driving me crazy lol, I just started using Anaconda and have not had this program with any other program. But thank you

Comment: no problem. I really like Anaconda. Took me a while to figure this out, but at the prompt I type Spyder and the spyder program opens.